# Huge files when saving SVM models with e1071

Tags: r, svm

I normally use the Support Vector Machines implementation provided by R `e1071` package. Recently, I needed to save the trained models to use them later in a different function and so I tried with the `save` command. Saving the model took something like 2-3 minutes generating files of 400 MB! I was surprised because the data structure in my workspace were quite small (< 50 KB). I am training regression SVMs with two inputs with less than 1000 samples so I didn't expect to have large saved files. Even checking the structure with `dput` didn't help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to save the models using the `dump` command but I realised that the command wasn't able to save the attributes. I've checked the attributes list and I found this attribute of the `terms' field:

```
$.Environment
<environment: 0x2bd1c00>
```

I realised that the SVM model has a "link" with the environment when it was created and in fact, after checking, I discovered that when I build the SVM models with the `svm` command the workspace contains some very big data frames. So the solution is easy: just delete all your unneeded data structures before returning/saving your SVM model to avoid huge saved data files